# Create new flow file for each attribute where key contains specific pattern

Tags: apache-nifi

I am struggling to figure how to split a flow file based on attributes.

Example of what I want to do:

1. Generate a flow file with the following attributes

```
 - Attribute 1
 - ... 
 - Attribute N
 - xyz 1
 - ...
 - xyz M
```

2. Create one flow file for each attribute where the name contains `xyz`.
   Flowfile `j` should have the following attributes:

```
 - Attribute 1
 - ... 
 - Attribute N
 - xyz (which contains the value from xyz j from the inital flowfile)
```

How do I get the result described in the second step?

Comment: what about script?

Comment: @dagget I actually wrote a script. However, I was thinking that if this can be done using an existing processor this should be used instead. At the moment I end up quite often writing custom scripts and I try to reduce that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the DuplicateFlowFile processor. Since you're the one generating the flow files and attributes, you should be able to use DuplicateFlowFile which adds the `copy.index` attribute for which copy (0-based) the flow file is. If you need to add 1 to it you can use UpdateAttribute downstream to set `copy.index` to the value `${copy.index:plus(1)}`